# Drupal docker image not able to connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, drupal

I am using docker on Ubuntu 18.04 having Drupal 8 and MySQL images. Also using Nginx as a web server (not an image in docker). Now during the installation of Drupal 8 on port 8080, it's not connecting to MySQL server. I am getting the error as:
[Error by drupal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PciZz.png)

I am entering the correct database username and password.
But I am not sure about the [advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dOKU.png).

I have tried the host as my-ip:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080 but it didn't work.

Comment: The error message indicates that you use unix sockets file to connect to mysql and mysql cannot file the indicated socket file. Drupal uses pdo to connect to mysql. The duplicate question is about fixing this error in pdo.